# Is there a python equivalent to javascript's shorthand for setting key:value pairs where the local variable name is the same as the key name?

Tags: javascript, python

In javascript, say we have two local variables `name` and `age`, and we want to create an object literal (dictionary) in the form:

```
let person = {
    name: name,
    age: age
}
```

This assignment can be shortened to this statement with the same outcome:

```
let person = {
    name,
    age
}
```

Is there an equivalent shorthand for this in python? Or do dictionaries have to be written like this?

```
person = {
    "name": name,
    "age": age
}
```

Comment: No, python doesn't have this kind of shorthand. It also doesn't have destructuring, to save you another question.

Comment: Oof. That's unfortunate. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You could call `locals()` to get _all_ of the local variables.

Comment: @jabaa One-liner answers like this are not generally considered good. I'm not sure how to provide supporting documentation, it's proving a negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's nothing built-in that does this.

You could define a function that does it, but you'd have to pass it the `locals()` dictionary so it can access those variables.

```
def dictvars(l, *names):
    return {name: l[name] if name in l else globals()[name] for name in names}

name = "myname"
def makeperson(age):
    person = dictvars(locals(), "name", "age")
    return person

print(makeperson(20)) # {'name': 'myname', 'age': 20}
```